# Xero SDK is allow to access for 30 mins

Tags: xero-api

I Created a public app in Xero and integrate it in my .net MVC application using XERO SDK,
While i Connect to xero it allow me only for 30 mins, after that authentication token got expire. How can I manage it without expire time?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid you can't. As mentioned on the doc - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/public-applications - access token on Public application expire after 30 minutes.

You need to use other application types - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/api-application-types